# Why can't the compiler deduce the Functor type in the Free Applicative examples?

Tags: haskell, applicative, free-monad

```
module Main where

data Toy b next =
    Output b next
  | Bell next
  | Done

data FixE f e = Fix (f (FixE f e)) | Throw e

-- The working monadic function
catch :: (Functor f) => FixE f e1 -> (e1 -> FixE f e2) -> FixE f e2
catch (Fix x) f = Fix (fmap (`catch` f) x)
catch (Throw e) f = f e

-- Type error
applicate_fixe :: (Functor f) => FixE f (e1 -> e2) -> FixE f e1 -> FixE f e2
applicate_fixe a b = a `catch` (`fmap` b)

-- Type error
applicate_fixe' :: (Functor f) => FixE f (e1 -> e2) -> FixE f e1 -> FixE f e2
applicate_fixe' (Throw f) b = fmap f b
applicate_fixe' (Fix f) b = Fix (fmap (`applicate_fixe` b) f)

main :: IO()
main = print "Hello."
```

---

```
C:\!Various_Exercises\Haskell_Exercises\Free_Monad_Stuff\test.hs: 15, 33
Could not deduce (Functor (FixE f)) arising from a use of `fmap'
from the context (Functor f)
  bound by the type signature for
             applicate_fixe :: Functor f =>
                               FixE f (e1 -> e2) -> FixE f e1 -> FixE f e2
  at test.hs:14:19-76
In the second argument of `catch', namely `(`fmap` b)'
In the expression: a `catch` (`fmap` b)
In an equation for `applicate_fixe':
    applicate_fixe a b = a `catch` (`fmap` b)
C:\!Various_Exercises\Haskell_Exercises\Free_Monad_Stuff\test.hs: 18, 31
Could not deduce (Functor (FixE f)) arising from a use of `fmap'
from the context (Functor f)
  bound by the type signature for
             applicate_fixe' :: Functor f =>
                                FixE f (e1 -> e2) -> FixE f e1 -> FixE f e2
  at test.hs:17:20-77
In the expression: fmap f b
In an equation for applicate_fixe':
    applicate_fixe' (Throw f) b = fmap f b
```

I am going off [this tutorial](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) trying to figure out the Free Monad and as an exercise I am trying to do the Applicative function as well. To be honest, I am not sure what those errors are supposed to mean.

Also I am not sure what the type signature for the `data FixE f e = Fix (f (FixE f e)) | Throw e` is supposed to be exactly. At first I thought `f (FixE f e)` is supposed to be a tuple, but it does seem like it is one argument, therefore the `(FixE f e)` part is actually a type argument to the first `f`. But if that is the case shouldn't the `f` inside `FixE f e` also require a type argument as well?

Edit:

```
applicate_fixe :: (Functor f) => FixE f (e1 -> e2) -> FixE f e1 -> FixE f e2
applicate_fixe (Fix f) b = Fix (fmap (`applicate_fixe` b) f) -- Works as the f argument in fmap is a functor
applicate_fixe (Throw f) (Fix b) = fmap f b -- The b is of type f (FixE f e1) so it is clearly a functor and yet the type system rejects it.
```

Before anything, I do not understand this last part. Also what exactly should have an instance of functor defined? `f` should already has that constraint in the above definition.

Edit2: Maybe you means that FixE should have a Functor instance.

```
instance Functor f => Functor (FixE f) where
  fmap f (Fix x) = fmap f x -- Type error
  fmap f (Throw e) = Throw (f e)
```

Here is my best shot, but it complains that the type f is too rigid in the first line.

Comment: You need to define an actual instance of `Functor` to use `fmap`. You have already defined `>>=` for `FixE f` and `return` is `ThrowE` so you can use the default implementations for `Functor` and `Applicative`.

Comment: I do not think this is what the type error is about. Well I sort of understand what they mean now, but what really surprises me is that when I change `applicate_fixe'' (Throw f) b = fmap f b` to `applicate_fixe' (Throw f) (Fix b) = fmap f b` I still get a type error. This confusing because `b` in `Fix b` really is a functor and yet the compiler still won't accept it.

Comment: You need to either add `instance .. => Functor (...) where fmap = ...` explicitly or using the `deriving` mechanism (possibly standalone). If you don't, Haskell does not equip your type with any instance (not for `Functor`, nor for `Eq`, `Show`, ... or any other class).

Comment: @chi, well, you do get two non-standard classes for free with sufficiently recent compilers. `Typeable` and `Coercible` don't need to be derived explicitly.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: @melpomene No, that still gives me type errors.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `fmap f (Fix x) = Fix (fmap (fmap f) x)`?

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, that is it. Did not see that one coming. Also changing `applicate_fixe (Throw f) (Fix b) = fmap f b` to `applicate_fixe (Throw f) b = fmap f b` now fixes the type error. I guess I have my applicative right there.

Answer (score 1):

```
module Main where

data Toy b next =
    Output b next
  | Bell next
  | Done

instance Functor f => Functor (FixE f) where
  fmap f (Fix x) = Fix (fmap (fmap f) x)
  fmap f (Throw e) = Throw (f e)

data FixE f e = Fix (f (FixE f e)) | Throw e

-- Monadic function
catch :: (Functor f) => FixE f e1 -> (e1 -> FixE f e2) -> FixE f e2
catch (Fix x) f = Fix (fmap (`catch` f) x)
catch (Throw e) f = f e

-- Applicative function
applicativeFixE :: (Functor f) => FixE f (e1 -> e2) -> FixE f e1 -> FixE f e2
applicativeFixE (Fix f) b = Fix (fmap (`applicativeFixE` b) f)
applicativeFixE (Throw f) b = fmap f b

main :: IO()
main = print "Hello."
```

Based on the comments I managed to implement the applicative function. I am not completely sure why the above works yet versus some of the alternative I've tried, but it type checks.

Thanks everyone.